# filtering out elements in string PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a database with youtube videos stored as iframe urls. what i want to do is show the youtube thumbnail next to each video using some basic replacement commands. i would like to run a function in php that would automatically find the content, strip out the iframe tags and leave a function with just the id.

in the third field i have the code so:

```
echo $galleryitems[$i][2]
```

would return

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/scYj-bDEaKI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

im not really sure of any other way to do this, and since all the codes are the same, i'd like to strip out these parts from the code:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
```

and

```
?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
```

i am thinking a `str_replace` would suffice? what i'd like in the end is a function `$strLink = scYj-bDEaKI` (just the video id)

looked through SO a bit and tried this:

```
$galleryitems[$i][2] = preg_replace('/<iframe[^>]*>(.*?)<\/iframe>/', '', $strLink, 1);

echo $strLink;
```

but returned nothing. Eyes turning square, thanks for any help!

Comment: oh... thats why people hate those nice "out of nowhere" variables of php. you are using preg_replace wrong. `$strLink = preg_replace('/<iframe[^>]*>(.*?)<\/iframe>/', '', $galleryitems[$i][2], 1); ` should work better for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, don't parse HTML with RegEx.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
if ($items->length) {
    $url = basename(parse_url($items->item(0)->getAttribute('src'), PHP_URL_PATH));
}
```

Example [in codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gdrPwq)

Comment: Thanks Ranty, this is pretty good stand alone–—but when i embed this into the document it is parsing all the individual id's onto one line… where as each one should be exported individually. does this have to do with the DOM element?

Comment: @Anthony I'm not sure what you mean. Is the problem that all video ids are assigned to the same variable `$url`? You can use an array instead, I updated the answer for it. If it's not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: spoke too soon, was a problem with an unclosed tag, whoops! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For PHP RegEx syntax, you can refer

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

```
$s = '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/scYj-bDEaKI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
echo preg_replace('/<iframe.* src="http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/(.*?)\?.*<\/iframe>/', '$1', $s);
```